# docker execute test cases with AWS Glue 4.0 image

Tags: docker, shell, aws-glue, docker-container

I was using the below command and it was working fine (with glue1.0 image)

docker run --rm -it -v path\to\my\src\folder:/code amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_1.0.0_image_01 bash -c "ls -ltr code"

It works fine, however when I run it amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01 it shows the below error :
/usr/bin/bash: /usr/bin/bash: cannot execute binary file